# Add extra field to result after queryset for context rendering

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

Currently I want to do something like this:

```
entity_info = get_object_or_404(Entity, pk=entity_id)
entity_info.review = 5
```

I can add field and pass to render and it works fine. However, now I want to add lots of fields at once, preferably merging with a dictionary. Something like this:

```
entity_info.update(new_dict)
```

May I know how to this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the dictionary's items, and use [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr).

```
entity_info = get_object_or_404(Entity, pk=entity_id)
for key, value in new_dict.items():
    setattr(entity_info, key, value)
```

This should work fine for attributes. You might have to something else if you are assigning to many to many fields.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Is there a more pythonic/shorter way of doing this?

Comment: Using `setattr` is a standard Python technique. It's only two lines, how short do you want it to be? ;)

Comment: I am just greedy :) Tks